# MongoDB after-installation error, couldn't connect to server

Tags: server, database, mongodb

I was following the (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) instructions to install MongoDB.
After completing till 4th step, i.e., after running the following command:-

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

when I run `mongo` command to get the CLI, I am getting the following error:-

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-04-20T12:02:10.947+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-04-20T12:02:10.999+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Also when I run `sudo service mongod start`, nothing happens. But when after that, I run `sudo service mongod status`, I get the following error:-

```
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-04-20 12:04:50 IST; 37s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 28034 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exite
 Main PID: 28034 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Apr 20 12:04:50 Inspiron-N5010 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free
Apr 20 12:04:50 Inspiron-N5010 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, 
Apr 20 12:04:50 Inspiron-N5010 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed s
Apr 20 12:04:50 Inspiron-N5010 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'e
lines 1-11/11 (END)
```

Can anyone help in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the package is broken or package installation was interrupted.
Run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

It will repair the package.

Also you first have to start the *mongod* server to use its cli.

So first run:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

and then run

```
mongo
```

This will open the mongodb cli.